# Funny markers in 'git log -p' output

Tags: git

I did a 'git log -p ..origin/xxxx' and got markers such as: '-<<<<<<< Updated upstream' and '->>>>>>> Stashed changes', what does it mean and where is it explained?

Answer (score 1):

`git log -p` will simply show the log and prints the patch between two versions.

`<<<<<<<`, `========` and `>>>>>>>>>>` are conflict markers, used to highlight textual conflicts to users when merging or applying a stash

see the [man page for git-merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_how_conflicts_are_presented) for examples

Comment: I actually got some help from the #git irc-channel. I had confused things. 'git log -p' will show the diffs of every commit in the history range, while 'git diff' just shows the diff between two commits. That's why my 'git diff' didn't show those markers.